# Transform equation into Mathieu equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ok. So the problem is:

Show that the damped equation

$\ddot{x} + k\dot{x} + (\gamma + \beta cos(t))x = 0$

can be transformed into a Mathieu equation by the change of variable $x = ze^{\mu t}$ for a suitable choice for $\mu$

Second attempt at solution:

We have:

$x=ze^{\mu t}$

$\dot{x}=\mu z e^{\mu t} + \dot{z}e^{\mu t}$

$\ddot{x} = \mu^2 ze^{\mu t}+2\mu \dot{z}e^{\mu t} + \ddot{z} + e^{\mu t}$

Inserting this into our equation gives, after some changing around:

$\ddot{z}e^{\mu t} + (2\mu + k)\dot{z}e^{\mu t} + (\mu^2 + k\mu + \gamma + \beta cos(t))ze^{\mu t} = 0$

We then choose $\mu$ so that $2\mu + k = 0$.  By doing this, and dividing both sides with $e^{\mu t}$ we obtain:

$\ddot{z} + (\mu^2 + k\mu + \gamma + \beta cos(t))z = 0$

And now we just perform a simple change of variable, as shown in my last post, and we are done!

Does it look OK now? :)

Comment: Note that the change of variables you are performing says $x(t) = z(t) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mu t}$, thus $\dot{x}(t) = \mu z(t) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mu t} + \dot{z}(t) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mu t}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right.  Thanks.  For some reason I thought of this as a constant.  Think I need to get back to the drawing board for a while.  Suddenly this got more complicated!

Comment: Hi.  I've tried a new approach to the problem.  Would be very grateful if you could look at it again.